# Specifying URL content path of image with SCSS

Tags: css, sass, mendix

I'm trying to implement some custom SCSS to a Mendix App that i'm building. I've added the following into .scss file as suggested by a Mendix community post.

```
.mx-name-tabPage1::before{
    content:url(..img/icon_details.png);
}
```

However, the icon doesn't display when i run the app in localhost.

I can inspect the element in Chrome edit it accordingly, i've found that the following content format works when editing the styles directly in the inspect window:

```
content: url(img/DMS$Images$icon_details.png)
```

I can't however enter '$' in Mendix as it throws an error. I'm looking to make this work within both localhost and when deployed in Mendix Cloud.

Any suggestions where i might be going wrong?